# Does hub.docker.com use "--no-cache" for automated builds?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am analysing some slightly strange behaviour in our automated build processes, which lead me to ask:

Does hub.docker.com use the `--no-cache` option when performing automated builds?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. The build process is currently:

1. `git clone --recursive --depth 1 -b branch $URL`
2. Extract `Readme` and `Dockerfile`
3. `docker build -t tagname --nocache`
4. Tar and upload the build context to S3 bucket
5. Push image (with all layers) to Registry
6. Worker or Builder cleans up build residue (mounted volumes, etc)

Comment: That's great and useful information. To qualify your answer - can I ask how you know this?

Comment: I am the Docker Developer Support Manager. I've spoken directly with the engineers who've written the Automated Build system.

Comment: Great information. Will the docker hub ever support cached builds? Or is  it this way because they don't want people to use the hub as a production build server?

Comment: "ever" is a long time. You can be sure that if we do offer it, we'll publicize it widely as a valuable new feature.

Comment: does this mean any apt-get install something command in the docker file, even if not changed between version will cause a newer large to be created and requires the client to redownload it?

Comment: I don't thin this answer is correct as of 2019.  I have this line in my Dockerfile `RUN pip3 install git+https://github.com/my/awesome-package`, and on the Dockerhub build logs it says `---> Using cache` `---> d09fb4ccb0bd` despite the fact that my repo has changed.  In the auto build settings, however, there is a enable build caching option, which you can de-select.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this was not the case for me. I had to end up rebuilding the image with the --no-cache flag.  Then push the image up to docker hub.
Admittedly the dockerfile used was not with best practice as it involved a "git pull".  Oh well!